# Find which phrases have at most one capital letter

Tags: php, regex

I am using RegEx (php) to find out which Addresses have one or less capital letters. For example:

av. St Joan 128 (Not match)
Av. st joan 122 (match)
av. St joan 212 (match)
Av. St.joan 121 (Not match)
AV. st joan 232 (Not match)

Comment: So, post your RegEx and describe the problem.

Comment: **Not Clear Enough** Please clarify your question

Comment: Just one capital letter, that is it?

Comment: what about `o` that you said at first?

Comment: I think you need a **regex** to find out which line contains just **one capital letter** and has an `o`, Am I right?

Comment: I need a regex to find out which of the address have one or less,ie, no capital letter. The o does not care

Comment: You can also check, if the string does not have at least two upper: [`[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]`](https://eval.in/829636)

Comment: `^[^A-Z]*(?:[A-Z][^A-Z]*)?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume you just need pattern not `php` code, otherwise comment me please to delete the answer.

A simple negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]).*$
```

It does not match any entire line that has more than **one** capital letter.

And as you commented:
*I need a regex to find out which of the address have one or less,ie, no capital letter*
It also matches **no capital letter**

So it just matches lines with **just one capital letter** or matches lines with **no capital letter**

for the input:

```
av. St Joan 128 (Not maach) | more than one
Av. st joan 122 (match)     | just one
av. St joan 212 (match)     | just one
Av. St.joan 121 (Not match) | more than one
AV. st joan 232 (Not match) | more than one
av. tt joan 212 (match)     | no one
```

the output is:

```
Av. st joan 122 (match)     | just one
av. St joan 212 (match)     | just one
av. tt joan 212 (match)     | no one
```

### [`^(?!.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/lSrThQ/4)

NOTE: 
for inverting the match, you can simply change `?!` to `?=`:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]).*$
```

And it matches:

```
av. St Joan 128 (Not maach) | more than one
Av. St.joan 121 (Not match) | more than one
AV. st joan 232 (Not match) | more than one
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked fine! ^(?!.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]).*$

Answer (score 3):

Using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$strings = [
    'av. St Joan 128',
    'Av. st joan 122',
    'av. St joan 212',
    'Av. St.joan 121',
    'AV. st joan 232'
];

$results = preg_grep('~^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*$~', $strings);
```

The pattern is simple and describes a whole string *(using anchors to figure the beginning and the end of the string)*.

Breakdown:

```
^               #match start of the string
[^A-Z]*         #match zero or more (greedily) non-uppercase characters
[A-Z]?          #match zero or one uppercase character
[^A-Z]*         #match zero or more (greedily) non-uppercase characters
$               #match end of the string
```

Meaning, that the string may have unlimited non-uppercase characters, but the uppercase letter can only occur zero or one time.  If the pattern finds a second uppercase character (anywhere), it is instantly a mis-match/fail.

Note that you can also use @bobblebubble pattern with the `PREG_GREP_INVERT` option to exclude strings that match:

```
$result = preg_grep('~[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]~', $strings, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Comment: can you explain your regex pattern?

Comment: I was trying to find a patten with look-around but yours is better +1

Comment: the `[^A-Z]` at the end is a little dangerous, because it can match **the next** line if the next line has no **capital letter** So it is better to use `[^A-Z\n\r]*$`

Comment: match newline as well [`^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]*[^A-Z]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/lSrThQ/1)

Comment: @k-five Casimir is considering the input text to be an array of single-line strings -- which is why he is using `preg_grep()`.  If the input data is not an array, but a mutli-value, multi-line string, then just use the `m` flag with `preg_match_all()`.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YuBmgL/1)  If it is just one value at a time, `preg_match()` will do.

Comment: Yes, `^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*$` works, but it has to do quite a bit of backtracking to determine failure on strings having more than one CAP. A more efficient way to phrase this would be: `^[^A-Z]*(?:[A-Z][^A-Z]*)?$`

Comment: @k-five: I take the term *phrase* (from the title) as *string*, that's why I don't take account of eventual newlines, my goal is to test a whole string. That's why I use `preg_grep` to filter an array and not `preg_match_all` to search a string.

Comment: @ridgerunner: indeed, I think of that at the beginning, but after testing it with the example strings It didn't seem so interesting, I decided to keep it simple. About optimisation, I think that using a possessive quantifier is better in this case than unrolling the pattern: `^[^A-Z]*+[A-Z]?+[^A-Z]*$`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use PHP [`Preg_Match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all occurances of your pattern.

You can define the pattern as being any capital letter, using PCRE so:

> `[A-Z]` = A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

Example:

```
$upper = "string oF Occurances";
$count = preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/",$upper);

// $count shows the number of upper case letters found in string    
// $count = 2

if ($count == 1){
     print "string ".$upper." has one Capital letter."; 
 }
```

> *I am working on the assumption you are seaching on a* per string 
>   *basis rather than* per row *basis, as in, your exampled text is five
>   strings each of one row.*

Comment: This post does not satisfy the question requirements.

Comment: @mickmackusa to be honest the exact question requirements are pretty vague. This is a solution using regex and PHP, other solutions are regex only. I don't see how this solution *doesn't* satisfy the requirements seeing as how *the question doesn't explicitly state any requirements!*.

Comment: The zero or one uppercase part is pretty clear.  Casimir's answer uses php too.  No need for exclamation.

Comment: @mickmackusa simply use the `if` statement to compare `$count` to the given criteria. It's not that complicated.